# Angular web based code editor using monaco

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, dependency-management, code-editor

In my project, we developed an online code editor using Monaco editor.

Now we want to add an angular editor for this. For that, we need NPM support(we want to install NPM dependencies from the editor).

Cany anyone suggests how can I develop this feature in my angular project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would either generate the package.json file in your editor which would then later be used offline to import the packages, or you would load angular as a CDN. Angular uses Typescript, so that would be your real problem, to compile it online.